# How to configure video / audio autoplay policy in a UWP WebView?

Tags: video, webview, uwp, microsoft-edge, autoplay

### Problem

*FYI this has also been raised on GitHub -> https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/issues/245*

When using a WebView in my voice driven UWP app, HTML `<video />` / `<autoplay />` elements sometimes do not autoplay. The following error is returned when calling HTMLMediaElement.play() method : `AbortError`

After reading through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/browser-features/autoplay-policies this could be because there was no previous user gesture made.
The problem is in voice driven apps, a "gesture" is not a "click" or a "tap", is a user spoken command.

### Possible solution

I would like to be able to allow autoplay without requiring user-gestures like clicks, taps first. Same to what electronjs already provides via autoplay policy.

### Attempted solutions

- Faking click events

### Similar issues

https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/505
https://github.com/bbc/VideoContext/issues/66

Comment: Hi, currently `WebView` seems does not provide this feature, I noticed that you have already submitted a Feature Request, you can wait for the response from the team